# Unable a open a local file on browser - ASP MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My Html link is well formatted . It resides inside my form ( post method ) . Although the  link opens up in a separate window, it doesn't work inside the form.  Is there any thing that hurts my link from opening ?

```
 <a href="file:///C:\uploads\test.doc">View Attachment</a>
```

Help appreciated...!

**Additional Info**

The target controller has a parameter of type FormCollection

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of your tags. It has to do with html and browsers. Is the entire site running from `file:///` or is it running off of a web server?

Comment: Please clarify: where "C:\uploads\test.doc" file is located (server, client, or even some other random machine).

Comment: Currently It's my own local pc ...  Later I will be using a Remote Windows server...

Comment: What's the url that is currently loaded in your browser? `file:///somepage.html` or `http://localhost/somepage.html`?

Comment: It is file:///something.doc

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I value SO . So before posting a question I make sure that do enough ground work to my level best . I tried the same link on a simple plain html and it was successful. Well , to me the question has something to do with the tags

Comment: @vikram I appreciate that you do this. Then there must be some important information that you're not giving us. No part of what you are asking involves hitting the server and asp.net is a server only technology. I understand that your link is to a file: schema, my question was about the page that contains the link,

Comment: Hi thanks @GeorgeMauer for the response . I have found a way to achieve this. I am using "FilePathResult" and I return the file on click  of the link    
    "return File(url, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet); " But the when I click it is downloaded as an undefined type .